# Flask app won't start, I am following the tutorial

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to follow this tutorial...

```
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/setup/#tutorial-setup
```

Trying to get a simple flask app to run. I think I have followed their code almost exactly, yet I am having problems. My code is....

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
    abort, render_template, flash

# configuration
DATABASE = ''
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

sandra_source= Flask(__name__)
sandra_source.config.from_object(__name__)

def main():
    sandra_source.run()

main()
```

I recognize the DB is not the same, but other than that, it is pretty spot on. However, I keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sandra_service'
```

My module is named sandra_service, so I'm not sure how this error is happening.

Stack trace

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sandra_service'
0     SandraImporter.load_module() c:\working\qzpkgs\quartz-14324978\win32_vc9\pylib\sandra\sandra_import.py:208
1     <module>()                   /playground/nbkiq0w/rester_app_root/services/sandra_service.py:20
2     Config.from_object()         D:\quartz\WINSLA~1\WIN32-~1\build\ext\noarch\lib\python2.6\flask\config.py:146
3 --> import_string()              D:\quartz\WINSLA~1\WIN32-~1\build\ext\noarch\lib\python2.6\werkzeug\utils.py:529
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're executing? It runs fine pasted into a file.

Comment: unfortunately, I am sure

Comment: Are you using execfile() or just python filename to run it?

Comment: As always, when posting a question involving an error, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: running in an IDE, so just hitting run

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sandra_service' 
0 SandraImporter.load_module() c:\working\qzpkgs\quartz-14324978\win32_vc9\pylib\sandra\sandra_import.py:208 
1 <module>() /playground/nbkiq0w/rester_app_root/services/sandra_service.py:202 Config.from_object() D:\quartz\WINSLA~1\WIN32-~1\build\ext\noarch\lib\python2.6\flask\config.py:146 3 --> import_string() D:\quartz\WINSLA~1\WIN32-~1\build\ext\noarch\lib\python2.6\werkzeug\utils.py:529 stack trace

Comment: @Zack for reference.... please [edit] that to your question - keeps the question and issues in one place (and it's somewhat difficult to read as a comment)

Comment: ok, put it with the question

Comment: @Zack would you be willing to just go to the command line and try executing the file with 'python filename' and report the results?

Comment: @Zack I have a sneaking suspicion that the IDE may be using execfile and not linking in all of the modules you need.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Does the problem persists when you run the program from `cmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a great answer or not, but I removed

```
sandra_source.config.from_object(__name__)
```

this line, and now the code seems to be at least compiling/running. Hopefully more issues won't present themselves later on.